# Disabled Select dropdown not showing option value in Reactive Forms Angular 4 Application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple Dropdown in a Angular Form which is loading only one option where object name coming through rest service.

I also want to disable the dropdown based on some condition. I know I can't use [disabled] property on HTML elements in reactive forms. So I am stuck with two options.
Either using [attr.disabled] or custom directive.

But both options not showing option value in disabled dropdown. Here is the code.

```
<select class="custom-select"
     name="objectName"
     id="objectName"
     formControlName="objectNameDropDown"
     [attr.disabled]="conditionTrue ? 'disabled': null"
     *ngIf="!someCondition; else loadDifferentDropdown;">
       <option>{{object.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried to use ngModel too but I think it is not needed. I also used custom Directive in place of [attr.disabled] but it is producing same result. Dropdown is disabled and empty. Option value is there but it is not coming as selected.

**Note:- Above code is working fine if I place this dropdown out of angular form and use [disabled]="someCondition"**

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try this in component - this.form.get('objectNameDropDown').disable(); refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377103/disable-select-in-angular2

Comment: just related... is there a reason why you are using a select if you only have one possible value? Wouldn't an input be better? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you using reactive form, you have to disable it from formbuilder itself as below example

```
this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    objectNameDropDown: [{value:"", disabled: true}],  
});
```

Comment: I can't use disabled true here. Disabled true false is completely depend on other radio button selection on my form. By default that section is disabled and will come into play when certain condition is true.

Comment: You may invoke function by radio button selected, re-set control of the form group.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I finally used something like this :

```
this.form.getRawValue().objectNameDropDown;
```

Comment: I can't use any component here in my case. Disabled true or false is completely depend on other radio button selection on my form. By default that section is disabled and will come into play when certain condition is true.

Comment: You can disable it in your ts file by calling

 this.form.get('objectNameDropDown').disable();